# i run the makemigration code and i receive many errors

Tags: django, django-models

i'm new in django 
i want to create a business_plan application 
i the step to create my models
i have a creating many class in my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import *

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type=((1,"admin"),(2,"staff"))
    user_type=models.CharField(default=1,choices=user_type,max_length=10)


class Entrepreneur(models.Model):
    id_models= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE())
    nom_et_prenom=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_naissance=models.DateField()
    adresse_entr=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    telephone=models.IntegerField()
    statut_social=(('ce','celébataire'),
               ('ma','marié'),
               ('di','divorcé'),
               ('ve','veuf'),
               )
    occupation=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    niveau_scolaire=(
        ('pri','primaire'),
        ('sec','secondaire'),
        ('cap','certificat aptitude professionel'),
        ('btp','brevet technicien professionel'),
        ('bts','brevet technicien superieur'),
        ('lic','license'),
        ('mai','maitrise'),
        ('mas','mastere'),
        ('doc','doctorat'),
                )
    niveau_scolaire=models.CharField(default='ser',choices=niveau_scolaire,max_length=50)
    annnee_exp=models.IntegerField()
    email=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Projet(models.Model):
    id_models=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE())
    nom_projet=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lieu_implantation=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type_projet=(
        ('ser','service'),
        ('com','commerce'),
        ('agr','agricuture'),
        ('ind','industrie'),
        ('IT','technologie information'),
        ('art','artisanat'),
        ('tor','tourisme'),
    )
    type_projet=models.CharField(default='ser',choices=type_projet,max_length=50)
    produit=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id_promoteur=models.ForeignKey(Entrepreneur,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Admin(models.Model):
    id_admin=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    objects=models.Manager()


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type=((1,"admin"),(2,"staff"))
    user_type=models.CharField(default=1,choices=user_type,max_length=10)
```

this is my files manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os 
import sys


def main():
   os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'oasisconsuting.settings')
   try:
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
   except ImportError as exc:
    raise ImportError(
        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
        "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
        "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
    ) from exc
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when i run makemigration  after creating my classes i have this error:

```
 > (business) C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\oasisconsuting>python manage.py makemigrations
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
   main()
 File "manage.py", line 17, in main
 execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
 line 401, in execute_from_command_line
 utility.execute()
 File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
 line 377, in execute
 django.setup()
 File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
 apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
 File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in 
 populate
   app_config.import_models()
 File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in 
 import_models
 self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
 File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\oasisconsuting\businessplan\models.py", line 9, in 
 <module>
 class Entrepreneur(models.Model):
 File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\oasisconsuting\businessplan\models.py", line 11, in 
 Entrepreneur
 admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE())
 TypeError: CASCADE() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'collector', 'field', 'sub_objs', and 
 'using'
```

where is my errors
can you help to fix this errors 
I use sqite3 database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you're calling `models.CASCADE` with the brackets after it. The last line on your traceback shows that 4 arguments is required because you're making a call to that function rather than just referencing it.

The line you require is:

```py
...

class Entrepreneur(models.Model):
    id_models= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove brackets in CASCADE as it not method but constant

```
class Entrepreneur(models.Model):
  admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Projet(models.Model):
  id_promoteur=models.ForeignKey(Entrepreneur,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: can you accept the answer ? (I would appreciate it) @user3828990

Comment: Green tick is not displayed under the votes thats why and i was not awarded the reputation for accepted answer.

Comment: sorry i'm new in stackoveflow please tel; what i should to do exactly to accept your answer

Comment: @user3828990 No problem

Comment: @user3828990 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

thank you i fix the errors it was about the barckets in models.CASCADE

but when i re_run the code it show an other errors:(i dont know if it's an error or warnings

```
> C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py:320: 
RuntimeWarning: Model 'businessplan.customuser' was already registered. Reloadin
g models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related 
models.
  new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with 
reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 
'CustomUser.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' 
clashes with reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 
'User.user_permissions' or 'CustomUser.user_permissions'.
businessplan.CustomUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.groups' 
clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 
'CustomUser.groups' or 'User.groups'.
businessplan.CustomUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 
'CustomUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 
'User.user_permissions'.

    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 
'CustomUser.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
businessplan.CustomUser_groups: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate 
model by 'businessplan.CustomUser.groups', but it does not have a foreign key to '
CustomUser' or 'Group'.
businessplan.CustomUser_user_permissions: (fields.E336) The model is used as an 
intermediate model by 'businessplan.CustomUser.user_permissions', but it does not hav
e a foreign key to 'CustomUser' or 'Permission'.
businessplan.Entrepreneur.admin: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 
  'CustomUser', which is either not installed, or is abstract. 
businessplan.Projet.admin: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 
  'CustomUser', 
   which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```